# VBA: Offset for cell relative to selection

Tags: vba, excel

I compare two Columns and pull the identical parts of the comparison-range to the right.

Now I want for the identical parts, the content in the cell 6 columns to the right of the compared data to be extracted too, in case there is a match.

It is some kind of double-related offset.

In other words, I want the cell 6 rows to the right of the comparison range to be offset another 8 cells further right.

The code looks like this:

```
Dim CompareRange, x , y As Variant

ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select

Set CompareRange = Worksheets("pumps").Range("B4:B67")

Dim SelDate As Date

For Each x In Selection
    For Each y In CompareRange
        If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 13) = x _
          And Range(x).Offset(0, 6).Select = SelDate _
          And Date1.Offset(0, 8) = SelDate
     Next y
 Next x
```

This part does not seem to be correct:

```
          And Range(x).Offset(0, 6).Select = SelDate _
          And Date1.Offset(0, 8) = SelDate
```

Comment: I'm not sure but try: `Date1.Offset(0, 8) = Range(x).Offset(0, 6)` Also Date1 appears to be nothing in your code, so you need to insert a valid reference to a cell here.

Comment: Ok guys, I found it in case anybody is interested:

For Each x In Selection
      For Each y In CompareRange
           If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 13) = x
           If x = y Then x.Offset(0, 14) = x.Offset(0, 5)
                                    
      Next y
    Next x

(Sorry, but I do not know how to show this in VB-code format...)

Comment: Post it as an answer, and then start every line with 4 spaces, in that way it is formatted as code.